# ZOHO CRM Webhook fails with HTTP error - 1

Tags: webhooks, zoho

I have created a workflow that fires when a new account is created.

The webhook always fires, and fails with http error - 1 (this is all logged in ZOHO)

The ZOHO documentation states that http error - 1 is becasue the ZOHO call cannot reach the server due to a firewall or some such, but offered no details.

I have thoroughly tested this and I believe the issue is on their end.  I have literally tested the GET from multiple locations around the world, including India, and it never fails.  Furthermore this is on AWS EC2 and the firewall rules for 80 and 443 are 0.0.0.0/0 (allow all).  There is no geoblocking in place.  No requests ever get near any log on my server, and I have other services using these APIs with no issue.

This simple test is basically a ping that accepts get parameters, sanitizes them, converts them to JSON, writes them to a log and returns the JSON payload with http status 200 to the caller.

This is what the webhook looks like in ZOHO:
https://**REMOVED**/api/ping?AccountID=${Accounts.Account Id}

A typical call should look something like:
[https://**REMOVED**/api/ping?AccountID=123456789](https://c9pets.erpecommerce.com/api/ping?AccountID=123456789)

I believe that it is something else and I'm hoping someone here has encountered and solved it, or at least has a suggestion I can pass to the people at ZOHO. This has been going on since 7/4.

Comment: You set trigger properly in Webhook that on which module you want to grab id ?

Comment: I believe so.  The webhook is actually firing, and showing a failure in the webhooks failure tab.  If I replace the webhook with an email notification I get the email.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After almost two weeks of back and forth, It turns out that the CA.bundle was not installed on my server.  This was causing the webservice call to fail leaving no trace on my server.